# Does Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.XELite.XELiveEventStreamer work with SSAS ring_buffer or event_stream?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, extended-events

I'm trying to extract extended events from a stream on a SSAS server with the following code:

```
    Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.XELite.XELiveEventStreamer xEvents = new XELiveEventStreamer("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI", "pju_RingBuffer");
    var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    
    xEvents.ReadEventStream(
        xevent =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xevent.Name);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        cancellationToken.Token
        );
    
    Console.WriteLine("Hit anykey");
    Console.ReadKey();
    cancellationToken.Cancel();
```

But nothing comes out.

It works for ring_buffers on a SQL server or if I save the SSAS server events to a .xel file.

A related question...
Is the documentation for the Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.XELite package available anywhere?